# Why didn't Ar-Gimilzôr make his second son Gimilkhâd throne heir?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion, numenor

Ar-Gimilzôr's oldest son who eventually became King Tar-Palantir was faithful to the Valar and a friend of the elves, unlike his younger brother Gimilkhâd who was like his father. Since Ar-Gimilzôr didn't care about tradition anyway during his reign, why didn't he make his younger son crown heir? By last will for instance. Just curious.

Comment: I suppose the laws of succession aren't just "traditions" and are harder to do away with.

Comment: @ibid Who/What would stand in the way of him doing so? Tar-Aldarion changed the law too so that his daugther Ancalimë could become Queen.

Comment: @AragornElessar The biggest difference was she was Tar-Aldarion's only child, which probably made it much more acceptable to the people and lords.  That's rather different than denying a first born son the crown over his beliefs and may have been too much, even if the Faithful were a minority.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer and its comments, there is some uncertainty over just how limited the power of the Kings of Numenor was to change such things, if it needed approval from anyone to change such laws officially.  But there may have been something else Ar-Gimilzôr wanted to avoid.

> 3175 Repentance of Tar-Palantir.  Civil war in Numenor.
>
> The Tale of Years, Second Age.

While the Faithful were a minority, they were not so small in numbers or power to deny Tar-Palantir the kingship.  Perhaps Ar-Gimilzôr knew, or feared, such conflict in his reign if he tried to deny the Kingship to his first born son because of his beliefs.

Answer (score 8):

He wanted to, but the law forbade it. There are two mentions of this: one in the Akallabeth (Silmarillion) and one in The Line of Elros (Unfinished Tales). No further information is given, but we can deduce that the kings of Numenor did not wield absolute power, and that their ability to make major constitutional changes was constrained by other factors. Exactly what these factors were is unknown, as far as I am aware.

Comment: There was a Council of Gondor I know, that restrained their kings.  Not sure if it was a Numenorean tradition carried over.  Though Tolkien Gateway suggests it might have been, on their page for the 'Council of Gondor' (their source is the Letters of Tolkien, one of the Tolkien books I don't have, so I can't check it.  It might just be confirmation of Gondor's council).

Comment: @suchiuomizu Yes there was a Council of Numenor, but where do you have it from that the councils would restrain their kings? They were just councils, no parliaments, they'd become more important for governance only if there's currently no monarch/heir.

Comment: @AragornElessar In Gondor's case the line that that letter is the source for, not sure how much of it is quoted directly from the letter, is "The Númenórean King of Gondor governed the realm with the frame of ancient law, of which he was administrator (and interpreter) but not the lawmaker. He consulted the Council in debatable matters of importance domestic, or external."  Suggesting something like a change to royal succession laws would require approval if Numenor was the same.  Unfortunately, again, I can't see the source letter to confirm.

Comment: @suchiuomizu That makes the council look like a parliament and the king like a constitutional monarch. That's contrary to what we know else about the rulers of Numenor, Gondor and Arnor. The King or Ruling Steward is indeed being understood as supreme legislator. The Councils are appointed by the Kings themselves btw.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is helpful but I accepted the other one because it provides additional options.

Comment: @AragornElessar To me it doesn't sound like a modern constitutional monarch. "The frame of ancient law" wouldn't be anywhere near a comprehensive system of concrete laws. It would say things like "murder is illegal; theft is illegal; the king can levy taxes; the king can raise armies; the king can't forcibly conscript soldiers", etc. Under such a system a monarch could have far more day-to-day practical power than a modern constitutional monarch, while still not being able to invent new laws out of whole cloth.

Comment: Quoting my copy of *Letters*, #244: ‘A Númenórean King [had the] decision in debate; but he governed the realm with the frame of ancient law, of which he was administrator (and interpreter) but not the maker. In all debatable matters of importance… even Denethor had a Council’. ‘Lawmaker’ for ‘maker’ is a trivial change; ‘Númenórean King of Gondor’ for ‘a Númenórean King’ is more dramatic, but I think the interpretation is correct. The meaning of the second part is quite different, though: *even Denethor*? Even the Steward had a Council, so certainly the King did? I’m not sure that follows.

Comment: Kings of Numenor definitely did have a Council, but its power was limited: "In a note on the 'Council on the Sceptre' at this time in the history of Numenor it is said that this council had no powers to govern the King save by advice; and no such powers had yet been desired or dreamed of as needful". (Unfinished Tales, Note 23 to "Aldarion and Erendis") [However, the use of 'yet' implies that it may have had greater powers in a later era - "Aldarion and Erendis" is in the late 800s Second Age]

Comment: @Ben definitely not like a modern constitutional monarch (in the current European sense of having very little governing power) but it does seem that there were some limits of 'customary law' or something - even when the succession laws were changed, they changed the law in general, didn't just decree that "X is my new heir"